# What does a question mark mean in the head of a Nix function definition?

Tags: nix

For example in:

```
{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}, compiler ? "ghc7102" }:
nixpkgs.pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler}.callPackage ./foo.nix { }
```

What does `compiler ? "ghc7102"` indicate? I assume a conditional - but can't find this mentioned under https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-constructs

Comment: Made the question itself more specific because the question mark is overloaded: in every other context (i.e., other than in the function head) it is the "Has Attribute" operator. For example, `e ? attrpath` tests whether set `e` contains the attribute denoted by `attrpath`; returns true or false. See [Nix expression language operators](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#table-operators) in the Nix manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is a [function with a set pattern and default values](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ss-functions). Everything before `:` is the pattern and the expressions after `?` are default values.