# What does a question mark mean in Nix when not used in a function definition?

Tags: nix

<sup>I'm aware of [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406588/what-does-a-question-mark-mean-in-nix), but that refers to `?` used in [function definitions with a set pattern](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#ss-functions) ([pinned](https://web.archive.org/web/20210412071147/https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#ss-functions)).</sup>

I looked up the implementation of `lib.makeOverridable` and came across [this line](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/d0a243c4babf502463293f289361f82359ff00c8/lib/customisation.nix#L85):

```hs
  ${if result ? overrideAttrs then "overrideAttrs" else null} = fdrv:
```

(Also learned that this kind of dynamic assignment is possible, so that's a bonus.)

Answer (score 4):

According to the table at [15.3. Operators](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sec-language-operators) ([pinned](https://web.archive.org/web/20210412071147/https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sec-language-operators)) in the [Nix manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/):

Table 15.1. Operators

```
| Name          | Syntax       | Description                     |
+---------------+--------------+---------------------------------+
|               |              | Test whether set e contains the |
| Has Attribute | e ? attrpath | attribute denoted by attrpath;  |
|               |              | return true or false.           |
+---------------+--------------+---------------------------------+
```

Examples:

```sh
$ nix repl
Welcome to Nix version 2.3.10. Type :? for help.

nix-repl> set = { a = 27; b = "lofa"; }

nix-repl> set ? a
true

nix-repl> set ? lofa
false

nix-repl> supset = { c = set; d = 7; }

nix-repl> supset ? c.a
true
```